# How does resistivity affect the susceptibility of a steel alloy to induction heating?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, electromagnetism, turbines

For context, my question is related to the use of heating to elongate studs for casing tightening and loosening. In turbine casing assembly, in addition to torquing the nuts, studs have holes drilled down their center which allows a heating element to be inserted. As the stud's temperature increases, it elongates. This creates a gap between the nut and the flange surface, which can easily be closed. When the stud cools, it returns to its original length plus a small elastic stretch, exerting an enormous force on the flange and its threads. This creates a very strong seal.

I am investigating replacing resistance based heating probes with a magnetic induction based heating probe, which offers advantages in heating rates and safety. This could also avoid dissipating heat to the casing flange and surrounding components, which would reduce cooling periods. This is important as currently using resistance based heaters, getting studs to temperature can take up to an hour. Excess heat dissipates outwards and the stud/flange assembly takes over 24 hours to cool.

My question is as follows:

If the steel alloy that the flange is made of has a lower resistivity (nearly half) compared to the alloy that the stud is made of, would it be less affected by the induced current, and therefore reach a lower temperature? Or are there more complex factors at play?

Example of induction bolt heating system -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vv2L7n3kYuI&embeds_referring_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2F&embeds_referring_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com&source_ve_path=MjM4NTE&feature=emb_title

Thank you